# wso2am-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT modify subscription tier save error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I run wso2 apim 2.0.1 snapshot on windows, and when i modify subscription tier and save, it report below exception, and although the bill plan changed , but the API still display **FREE** label.

```
[2016-08-12 15:30:02,504] ERROR - EventProcessorAdminService Error while deleting the execution plan file
org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.exception.ExecutionPlanConfigurationException: Error while deleting the execution plan file
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.delete(EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.java:124)
        ......
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /D:/emman/PROJECT/AA/apimgmt/wso2am-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT/repository/deployment/server/\executionplans
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.EventProcessorUtil.validateFilePath(EventProcessorUtil.java:387)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.delete(EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.j
ava:109)
        ... 65 more
[2016-08-12 15:30:02,539] ERROR - ThrottlePolicyDeploymentManager Error while deploying policy to global policy server.Error while deleting the execution plan file
[2016-08-12 15:30:02,541]  INFO - subscription-policy-edit:jag SubscriptionPolicy [policyName=Gold, description=Allows 5000 requests per minute, defaultQuotaPolicy=QuotaPolicy [type=requestCount, limit=RequestCountLimit [requestCount=5000,
toString()=Limit [timeUnit=min, unitTime=1]]]rateLimitCount=-1, tenantId=-1234,ratelimitTimeUnit=NA]
```

Comment: added one issue in wso2 apim github rep [link](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/1101)

Answer (score 0):

As per your logs, error happens due to invalid file path below.

```
/D:/emman/PROJECT/AA/apimgmt/wso2am-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT/repository/deployment/server/\executionplans
```

I had a look at [code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-event-processing/blob/v2.1.0/components/event-processor/org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/event/processor/core/internal/util/EventProcessorUtil.java#L387). It reads the first part of this path from `<RepositoryLocation>` tag of `carbon.xml` file. By default, it should look like this.

`<RepositoryLocation>${carbon.home}/repository/deployment/server</RepositoryLocation>`

Please verify if you have the same in `carbon.xml`. If you are getting this error with the same config, please change it to the absolute path like below and try again.

`D:\emman\PROJECT\AA\apimgmt\wso2am-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT\repository\deployment\server`

Comment: Are you using Cygwin by any chance?

Comment: No such issue with linux, i will use linux first.

Comment: This is already reported in WSO2 APIM Jira. It'll be fixed in master soon.
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5269

Answer (score 0):

To make your path more linux-like I used this trick.
Share your carbon home folder. Change carbon.xml setting RepositoryLocation in //machinenaam/share.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description, best with relevant code?